# Rails query slow but fast in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I'm trying to figure out why one of the queries in my rails app is under performing quite considerably. I'm using Postgres 9.3, and rails 4.0.3 with jRuby 1.7.10 so potentially it's an issue with the JDBC driver?

But basically, it's a VERY simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

The table contains `851` rows so it's hardly a massive dataset, so I'm expecting a fast query. When I execute this query in pgAdmin 3, I get exactly what I expect: all rows returned in anywhere between 15 and 35ms. Nice and fast!

From rails however it's a different story. Running the query in a rails console, the fastest I've been able to achieve is `189ms` whilst generally it is around the `200ms` mark. This query is run by calling `Table.all`

My initial thought was simply that ActiveRecord is adding overhead in the instantiation of 851 objects, so that's obviously slowing it down. To test this, I ran

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

There was a slight speedup, but again, almost all queries were taking around `150ms`, still a long way off the pgAdmin mark. As a last attempt I tried

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query_raw("SELECT * FROM table")
```

But this didn't improve the performance at all.

I'm really stumped now as to why this is so much slower, given that I am seeing a 10x performance decrease between pgAdmin and Rails. Having executed just the raw SQL in Rails, I know it's not ActiveRecord slowing things down, so I'm really confused now as to what is.

Does anyone know why this is so much slower than it should be?

**UPDATE**

I've done some more digging, and it seems to be in the way rails is handling Date fields. If I manually select all of the columns in the table, it is just as slow, but if I select them all except for `updated_at` and `created_at`, the query runs in around 2-4ms which is perfect!

My only issue now then, is how to get around this. Is there a way of fixing rails performance issue with dates, or having rails not parse them as dates and keep them as strings or similar?

**UPDATE 2**

So after doing some more digging and @stonehz pointing me to the bug raised from this post, I've upgraded to `Jruby 1.7.12` and `rails 4.1.0` and noticed a considerable speed up. It's it's not a lot closer to the performance of pgAdmin, but I think that without removing the date columns completely, I'm not going to get anything better. Below is the benchmark I'm now getting

```
SELECT *:                        4.080000   0.330000   4.410000 (  5.243000)
SELECT date_fields:              1.960000   0.020000   1.980000 (  2.032000)
SELECT * - date_fields:          3.070000   0.070000   3.140000 (  3.247000)
--------------------------------------------------------- total: 9.530000sec

                                     user     system      total        real
SELECT *:                        3.700000   0.060000   3.760000 (  4.663000)
SELECT date_fields:              1.790000   0.020000   1.810000 (  2.021000)
SELECT * - date_fields:          2.330000   0.060000   2.390000 (  3.180000)
```

This benchmark is querying 851 rows. The first test is a simple `SELECT *` statement. The second test only selects the date fields, and the final test selects all fields *except* for the date fields. Each query is being run 100 times to get the final result.

As this shows, the `select *` statement is now only taking ~4 seconds to run 100 times, so each query is taking only `40ms` which is much closer to the pgAdmin time of ~30ms. MUCH BETTER!

Comment: I'm not a ruby on rails guy, but without looking any further than SELECT * I can say that you should start by naming only the columns you need. ORM often go through a whole dog and pony show to turn * into a bunch names and what not, this could be adding some of the ms to your total time.  For quick experiment can you do SELECT 1 my_number FROM table and see how that performs?

Comment: Rails doesn't do any trickery with the query, it simply runs SELECT * without changing it into an individual column select. It does seem to speed up a bit in production mode though but not as much as I'd expect

Comment: If running your query from rails console you are still adding another layer which adds lines and lines of code to process and return a result set from the database. My opinion is I would expect it be slower by some degree and 154ms slower doesn't sound unreasonable. Pgadmin is written in C++ I would expect it to better handle processing result sets for display. Run the same query from psql and I bet it will beat out pgadmin or match it worse case. My point is the slow down is with Ruby/Rails/Active record not Postgres. And get rid of the SELECT * in all your production queries plz :).

Comment: hmm alright, will do some more testing. Don't worry I haven't actually put SELECT * in production code! That's just the query that rails is auto-generating for a particular use-case. No hard coded query of that

Comment: I found this question searching for the exact opposite problem. Semi-complex query in rails was 39ms and 1729ms in PgAdmin.

Comment: ha weird, that I would not expect to see

Comment: Does the problem occur if you type cast the dates to text in the query? If not, I'd expect it has to do with the type casting Rails does in the connection adapters.

Comment: I'm certain it is! I found that if I change the query to exclude the date fields it comes back in the same amount of time as pgAdmin. It's just annoying as we have some business logic that makes use of the date fields so we can't exclude them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have addressed the issue and opened couple tickets around the bug you found:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1662

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/540

Using Jruby 1.7.12 will improve performance around 5x (as their benchmarks imply)

Comment: Updating to `Jruby 1.7.12` and updating rails to 4.1.0 definitely boosts the speed a bit. I've updated the question with some more results but I think this is the closest I'll be able to get without completely excluding the date fields.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm really stumped now as to why this is so much slower, given that I am seeing a 10x performance decrease between pgAdmin and Rails. Having executed just the raw SQL in Rails, I know it's not ActiveRecord slowing things down, so I'm really confused now as to what is.

It's not ActiveRecord as much as it is your query.

When you run this query in pg admin, it doesn't *actually* run it insofar as I'm aware. PgAdmin makes a few assumptions on your usage, namely that you'll frquently end up with a huge set. In the interest of performance, it's more interesting touse a cursor so as to allow you to navigate the huge set by fetching rows as needed rather than all at once. I'd gather that this is precisely what is going on.

When you run the same query in your app, in contrast, you're responsible for doing this kind of thing. Or for that matter, not running this kind of query to begin with. Needing to select all rows from a database table is usually a sign that something's wrong in your app's design.

Comment: I agree that running select * is a bad idea, but this was just as a test, not the actual production query that is being executed :)